# I'm trying to make a wage calculator but when i try to print the wages it shows zeros

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**I'm trying to make a wage calculator.
I'm trying to make a wage calculator but when I try to print the wages it shows zeros. I'm using Tkinter**

```
app = Tk()
hoursWorkedWeek_text = IntVar()
hoursWorkedWeek_label = Label(app, text="Hours worked per week: ", font=("bold", 13), pady = 20)
hoursWorkedWeek_label.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)
hoursWorkedWeek_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=hoursWorkedWeek_text)
hoursWorkedWeek_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

**there are 3 more like this where it gets the rate etc**

```
_hpw = hoursWorkedWeek_entry.get()
hpw = float(_hpw)

_rph = rateEarnedPH_entry.get()
rph = float(_rph)

_oh = overtimeHours_entry.get()
oh = float(_oh)

_rot = rateForOvertime_entry.get()
rot = float(_rot)

def calculate():
    _salaryPerWeek = hpw * rph + oh * rot
    salaryPerWeek = str(_salaryPerWeek)

    _salaryPerMonth = salaryPerWeek * 4
    salaryPerMonth = str(_salaryPerMonth)

    _salaryPerYear = salaryPerMonth * 12
    salaryPerYear = str(_salaryPerYear)
    
    salaryPerWeek_text = "Your Weekly Salary is " + salaryPerWeek
    salaryPerMonth_text = "Your Monthly Salary is " + salaryPerMonth
    salaryPerYear_text = "Your Yearly Salary is " + salaryPerYear
    
    print(salaryPerWeek_text)

    T = Text(app, height=5, width=52)

    T.insert(tkinter.END, salaryPerWeek_text)
    T.insert(tkinter.END, salaryPerMonth_text)
    T.insert(tkinter.END, salaryPerYear_text)
```

**and then there is the Calculate button**

```
#Buttons
calculate_btn = Button(app, text="Calculate", width=12, command=calculate)
calculate_btn.grid(row=2,column=1, pady=20)

app.title("Salary Calculator")
app.geometry("700x400")

#Start program
app.mainloop()
```

**Can you please explain to me what was wrong? I'm new to programming
and a rating would be nice
Thank You**

Comment: There is not enough information to identify the issue, so it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: You need to call those `.get()` inside `calculate()`.

Comment: If the code you entered above is in fact your structure, then I see two things. One, your print statement is outside the scope of the function. You need to add a indention to it to move it inside the function scope where the variables are declared. Second, (and not to important) but there is a ` before the print statement which is not syntactically correct. Just remove it.